# google actions sdk: using third party server to build templated responses

Tags: google-cloud-functions, actions-on-google

My Google Actions project points to a Google Cloud Function as a webhook. In the google cloud function I am able to create the conversation responses using `conv.ask(...)`.

However, what I am trying to do is: build a generic conversation content framework that resides on **another server (also google cloud function)** where I would like to compose the response and send it back to the webhook function.

The relevant code in both these servers are like this:

```
// in the webhook function

app.intent('actions.intent.MAIN', (conv, input) => {
    // here I would like to call the second google function by
    // passing, say, the input and receiving a response that can
    // be passed on to the conv
    // something like 
    // assume request-promise is being used
    //
    var options = {
      method: 'POST',
      uri: '..',
      body: {...},
      json: true
    };
    rp(options)
     .then(resp => {
       conv.ask(resp) // this is what I would like to do
     });
 });
```

In the second Google Functions server, I am using express as middleware. Here on some logic templated responses get built

```
const .. 
const {
  SimpleResponse,
  BasicCard,
  ...
} = require('actions-on-google');
...
const express = require('express');
var app = express();
...
app.post('/main', function(req, res, next) {
  // here I would like to compose the response 
  // and send it to the earlier function
  var convresp = new SimpleResponse({...});
  ..
  res.send(convresp);  
  // this seems to be only sending the json 
  // and causes the receiving response to give an error
  // when applying to conv.ask in the above code
});
```

Question is: how should the response be sent from the second function so that it can be "pasted" to the `conv.ask` functionality in the first function?. Thanks

Comment: Are you planning to just send simple responses? You could just send the individual fields back and then compose them in your webhook.

Comment: No @NickFelker. In fact, the second server (being a logic based server) may send a combination of a simple Response + basic Card for example. The whole point of using the second server is: to de-couple the business logic that determines the response from the webhook. Just, btw, the long term thinking is that server 2 may be used by different webhooks called by different action projects. This is just to share what I am thinking architecturally. Thanks for the response.

Comment: Okay. In this case, you may see discrepancies between the classes and the raw JSON. You may want to generate the raw JSON in your webhook and set it to the conversation using `conv.json({...})`

Comment: Thanks @NickFelker. I did consider that but then thought that the advantage of using the `actions-on-google` node js library is lost. The convenience of creating functions for different response types is one of the advantages of the library. What is the need to re-invent the wheel and build my own library to return the raw json? Or am I missing out something?

Comment: The library's structure is not meant to be used this way, leading to some potential incompatibility issues doing it. The structure with the classes are meant so that you don't just send JSON directly into the `conv.ask` method, and typings are not preserved between network requests.

Comment: Thanks @NickFelker. Got it. However, since I **need** to build a separate business logic layer for my use-case where the conversation responses are being built, I am passing them on as json to the webhook and rebuilding them. :-(. Not something I am proud of ... but it works.